# Openvr get magnetometer data

Tags: virtual-reality, magnetometer, openvr

I am trying to get the Magnetometer data from the HTC VIVE using openvr lib. Any help and direction will be appreciated.

It will be ideal if i can access this in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of version 1.0.2 such API is not available.

Due to the nature of hardware abstraction, all device-specific raw sensory data are handled within the HMD driver. They don't need to and cannot be shared via the OpenVR API.